# How can i transform this menu to responsive?

Tags: html, css, menu

i have a vertical menu in my website, and my intention is to convert it to responsive like the rest of the template, but i can't.

Here is the css code:

```
    ul.form {
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
    max-width:250px;
    max height:300px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;     
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 

    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow:  1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);   
}

.form li a {
    width:250x;
    padding-left:20px;
    height:56px;
    line-height:50px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#686868;

    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    transition:all 0.2s linear;         
}

.form li a:hover {
    background:#efefef;
}

.form li a.lista {
    border-left:5px solid #b3cfd0;
}

.form li a.lista2 {
    border-left:5px solid #195d5c;
}

.form li:first-child a:hover, .form li:first-child a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.form li:last-child a:hover, .form li:last-child a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.form li a:hover i {
    color:#b3cfd0;
}

.form i {
    margin-right:15px;

    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    transition:all 0.2s linear; 
}

.form em {
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #ea4f35;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;        
    font-style: normal;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    line-height: 10px;
    height: 10px;       
    float:right;
}

.form li.selected a {
    background:#efefef;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul class="form">
    <li><a class="lista2" href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Portada</a></li>
    <li class="lista"><a class="lista" href="#"><i class="icon-info"></i>Servicios</a></li>
        <li><a class="lista2" href="#"><i class="icon-newspaper-o"></i>Noticias</a></li>
    <li><a class="lista" href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Quienes somos</a></li>
    <li><a class="lista2" href="#"><i class="icon-signout"></i>Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tv06s6wa/

PROBLEM DEFINITION:

How can i convert the existing menu, keeping its all styles as is, into a responsive menu for a mobile site?

Thanks for everything.

Comment: @media screen - google that.

Comment: So you've defined the problem. Now what have **you** done to try and solve it? At the moment, it seems like you're asking SO users to do all the work..and I know that's not what you meant...was it?

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, @media is what you want.  Something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .form {
    /*Place your mobile styles here*/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:480px) and (min-width:100px) {
      .form {
        /*shrink text size, containers, and everything else as desired*/
      }
    }
```

***Or.*** Have your full menu `display:none;` on all mobile, and trigger `display:block;` for your mobile specific menu only!

In either case @media relies on `<meta viewport` so something like below; or width device width etc, there are a few options.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
```